# How to display other view when RecyclerView is empty in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to display information that RecyclerView have no items, but I can't check if Firestore collection is empty. How to set some kind of listener which check if RecyclerView have items or not?

Comment: How are you populating the RV? Firebase UI? Or manually after a query / observe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Firebase UI (otherwise you would already have a query callback to hook into). In your FirestoreRecyclerAdapter, you can override [onDataChanged & onError](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/firestore/README.md#data-and-error-events):

```
typealias DataChangedListener = (count: Int) -> Unit
typealias ErrorListener = (error: FirebaseFirestoreException) -> Unit

class MyAdapter(
    options: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<MyModel>,
    private val onDataChangedListener: DataChangedListener = {},
    private val onErrorListener: ErrorListener = {}
) : FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<MyModel, MyViewHolder>(options) {

    ...

    // Notify Activity/Fragment/ViewModel
    override fun onDataChanged() = 
        onDataChangedListener.invoke(itemCount)

    // Notify Activity/Fragment/ViewModel
    override fun onError(e: FirebaseFirestoreException) = 
        onErrorListener.invoke(e)

}
```

You can use it like this:

```
recyclerView.adapter = MyAdapter(
            options,
            { count -> showHideNoData(count > 0) },
            { error -> showError(error) }
        )

...

fun showHideNoData(haveData: Boolean) { 
    recyclerView.isVisible = haveData
    noDataView.isVisible = !haveData
    errorView.isVisible = false
}

fun showError(error: FirebaseFirestoreException) {
    recyclerView.isVisible = false
    noDataView.isVisible = false
    errorView.isVisible = true
    // Logging & other UI changes
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you are right, I used FirebaseUI, I'm sorry I didn't mention that, I'll try it tonight :)

Comment: Works awesome! :D Thank you for your help one more time, problem was that I didn't know how to make listeners in anonimous way, cause I change Java for Kotlin. :)

Comment: It's a strange quirk... if you write a listener interface with 1 method in Java (known as a SAM interface), then you can implement it with a lambda in Kotlin. But if you write a SAM interface in Kotlin, you cannot use a lambda. So I prefer to alias a lambda signature (giving you the convenience of a lambda with the readability of an interface).

Comment: FYI - you can also pass in method references instead of lambdas, for example `{ error -> showError(error) }` could just be `::showError` (because the signature matches exactly)

Answer (score 0):

If it will be useful here is my solution. I simply called this function in the fragment where RecyclerView lives:

```
private fun setUpRecyclerView() {
    val viewManagerPortrait = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    val viewManagerLandscape = GridLayoutManager(activity, 3)
    val query = docRef.orderBy("title", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
    query.addSnapshotListener { p0, _ ->
        if (p0 != null) {

            if(p0.size() > 0) {
                emptyAds.visibility = View.GONE;
                listItems.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }else {
                emptyAds.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
                listItems.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
    }
    val options = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Item>()
        .setQuery(query,Item::class.java)
        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
        .build()
    mAdapter = ItemCardsAdapter(this,options)
    listItems.apply {
        setHasFixedSize(true)
        // use a linear layout manager if portrait, grid one else
        layoutManager = if(activity!!.resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
            viewManagerLandscape
        else
            viewManagerPortrait
        adapter = mAdapter
    }
}
```

As you can see the if statement (inside the SnapShotListener) on size checks whether the database at that reference is empty, showing a message in the layout instead of the RecyclerView.